# In multiple dropdown menu, how to disable an option if already selected in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I have 4 different dropdown fields with 5 options and I want to disable/remove an option from other fields if the option is already selected.

Screenshot:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J60pM.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcy9r.png)

DropDown Menu Code:

> ```
> String opemo1, opemo2, opemo3, opemo4;
> List<String> emoji = [
>     "❤️",
>     "",
>     "✌️",
>     "",
>     "",
>   ];
> ```

> ```
>           DropdownButtonFormField(
>                                   validator: (value) =>
>                                       value == null ? 'required' : null,
>                                   hint: Text('❤️'),
>                                   value: opemo1,
>                                   icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
>                                   iconSize: 36,
>                                   isExpanded: true,
>                                   style: TextType.regularDarkText,
>                                   onChanged: (newValue) {
>                                     setState(() {
>                                       opemo1 = newValue;
>                                       pollDataController.setop1Emoji(newValue);
>                                     });
>                                   },
>                                   items: emoji.map((opemo1) {
>                                     return DropdownMenuItem(
>                                       value: opemo1,
>                                       child: Text(opemo1),
>                                     );
>                                   }).toList(),
>                                 ),
> ```

Comment: you probably could do that by removing the emoji from the emoji list in the on change function. so when the user changes the emoji you can remove the new value from the emoji list and add the old one (using opemo1, opemo2, etc.) to the emoji list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage it you need to remove the selected emoji from `List<String> emoji`.

```
onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
        emoji.removeWhere((element) => element == newValue); /// This removed selected emoji.
        opemo1 = newValue;
        pollDataController.setop1Emoji(newValue);
    });
},
```

You can replace your `onChanged` with this snippet.